# Transform column into additional row

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

I have the below query (additional columns removed for simplicity) that I have two columns, `MERCHANDISE_AMT` and `FREIGHT_AMT`. Instead of separate columns I would like to output an additional row with the FREIGHT_AMT value in the `MERCHANDISE_AMT` column. I wanted to know if there is a way to do this without the use of a `UNION` operator ? All the other columns would contain the same values as the first row, except for `VOUCHER_LINE_NBR` which would be the next incremental number (i.e., 2) it's just for cases when there is a 'FREIGHT_AMT' populated than I need the additional row output with the value (of 'FREIGHT_AMT') in the 'MERCHANDISE_AMT' column.

```
SELECT CONCAT(A.BUSINESS_UNIT,A.VOUCHER_ID) AS INVOICE_ID, A.VOUCHER_LINE_NUM, 
CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM PS_DISTRIB_LINE 
                  WHERE BUSINESS_UNIT = A.BUSINESS_UNIT
                    AND VOUCHER_ID = A.VOUCHER_ID
                    AND VOUCHER_LINE_NUM = A.VOUCHER_LINE_NUM)                                                                             
          THEN 'ITEM' ELSE 'MISCELLANEOUS' END, A.MERCHANDISE_AMT, A.FREIGHT_AMT


FROM FROM PS_VOUCHER_LINE A
LEFT OUTER JOIN PS_DISTRIB_LINE B ON B.BUSINESS_UNIT = A.BUSINESS_UNIT AND B.VOUCHER_ID = A.VOUCHER_ID AND B.VOUCHER_LINE_NUM = A.VOUCHER_LINE_NUM
LEFT OUTER JOIN PS_VOUCHER C ON C.BUSINESS_UNIT = A.BUSINESS_UNIT AND C.VOUCHER_ID = A.VOUCHER_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN PS_VCHR_LINE_WTHD D ON D.BUSINESS_UNIT = A.BUSINESS_UNIT AND D.VOUCHER_ID = A.VOUCHER_ID AND D.VOUCHER_LINE_NUM = A.VOUCHER_LINE_NUM AND D.WTHD_ENTITY = 'IRS'
LEFT OUTER JOIN PS_VCHR_LINE_WTHD DD ON DD.BUSINESS_UNIT = D.BUSINESS_UNIT AND DD.VOUCHER_ID = D.VOUCHER_ID AND DD.VOUCHER_LINE_NUM = D.VOUCHER_LINE_NUM AND DD.WTHD_ENTITY = 'PA'
LEFT OUTER JOIN PS_VENDOR E ON E.BUSINESS_UNIT = B.BUSINESS_UNIT_GL AND E.VENDOR_ID = A.VENDOR_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN #CloudXWalk F ON F.BUSINESS_UNIT = B.BUSINESS_UNIT_GL AND (F.DEPTID = 'All' OR F.DEPTID = B.DEPTID)
LEFT OUTER JOIN #CloudCostCenter H ON H.BUSINESS_UNIT = B.BUSINESS_UNIT_GL AND H.DEPTID = B.DEPTID
LEFT OUTER JOIN #CloudProjectCodes G ON G.PS_PROJECT_CODE = B.PROJECT_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN PS_PYMNT_VCHR_XREF I ON I.BUSINESS_UNIT = A.BUSINESS_UNIT AND I.VOUCHER_ID = A.VOUCHER_ID

WHERE 
C.INVOICE_DT > '01-03-2019'
AND C.ACCOUNTING_DT < '06-01-2021'
--AND A.BUSINESS_UNIT = '90059'
AND I.PYMNT_ID = ''
AND C.CLOSE_STATUS <> 'C'
```

**Existing sample output:**

```
INVOICE_ID      VOUCHER_LINE_NUM    (No column name)    MERCHANDISE_AMT    FREIGHT_AMT
1100000720667   1                    ITEM               17480.820          58.24000
```

**Desired sample output:**

```
INVOICE_ID      VOUCHER_LINE_NUM    (No column name)    MERCHANDISE_AMT    
1100000720667   1                    ITEM               17480.820
1100000720667   2                    ITEM               58.24000
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `unpivot` from columns to new row

```
;WITH CTE AS (
SELECT CONCAT(A.BUSINESS_UNIT,A.VOUCHER_ID) AS INVOICE_ID, A.VOUCHER_LINE_NUM, 
CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM PS_DISTRIB_LINE 
                  WHERE BUSINESS_UNIT = A.BUSINESS_UNIT
                    AND VOUCHER_ID = A.VOUCHER_ID
                    AND VOUCHER_LINE_NUM = A.VOUCHER_LINE_NUM)                                                                             
          THEN 'ITEM' ELSE 'MISCELLANEOUS' END AS UnNamedColumn, A.MERCHANDISE_AMT, A.FREIGHT_AMT


FROM FROM PS_VOUCHER_LINE A
LEFT OUTER JOIN PS_DISTRIB_LINE B ON B.BUSINESS_UNIT = A.BUSINESS_UNIT AND B.VOUCHER_ID = A.VOUCHER_ID AND B.VOUCHER_LINE_NUM = A.VOUCHER_LINE_NUM
LEFT OUTER JOIN PS_VOUCHER C ON C.BUSINESS_UNIT = A.BUSINESS_UNIT AND C.VOUCHER_ID = A.VOUCHER_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN PS_VCHR_LINE_WTHD D ON D.BUSINESS_UNIT = A.BUSINESS_UNIT AND D.VOUCHER_ID = A.VOUCHER_ID AND D.VOUCHER_LINE_NUM = A.VOUCHER_LINE_NUM AND D.WTHD_ENTITY = 'IRS'
LEFT OUTER JOIN PS_VCHR_LINE_WTHD DD ON DD.BUSINESS_UNIT = D.BUSINESS_UNIT AND DD.VOUCHER_ID = D.VOUCHER_ID AND DD.VOUCHER_LINE_NUM = D.VOUCHER_LINE_NUM AND DD.WTHD_ENTITY = 'PA'
LEFT OUTER JOIN PS_VENDOR E ON E.BUSINESS_UNIT = B.BUSINESS_UNIT_GL AND E.VENDOR_ID = A.VENDOR_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN #CloudXWalk F ON F.BUSINESS_UNIT = B.BUSINESS_UNIT_GL AND (F.DEPTID = 'All' OR F.DEPTID = B.DEPTID)
LEFT OUTER JOIN #CloudCostCenter H ON H.BUSINESS_UNIT = B.BUSINESS_UNIT_GL AND H.DEPTID = B.DEPTID
LEFT OUTER JOIN #CloudProjectCodes G ON G.PS_PROJECT_CODE = B.PROJECT_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN PS_PYMNT_VCHR_XREF I ON I.BUSINESS_UNIT = A.BUSINESS_UNIT AND I.VOUCHER_ID = A.VOUCHER_ID

WHERE 
C.INVOICE_DT > '01-03-2019'
AND C.ACCOUNTING_DT < '06-01-2021'
--AND A.BUSINESS_UNIT = '90059'
AND I.PYMNT_ID = ''
AND C.CLOSE_STATUS <> 'C'
)

SELECT INVOICE_ID,VOUCHER_LINE_NUM - 1 + row_number() over (partition by INVOICE_ID order by (select NULL)) AS VOUCHER_LINE_NUM,UnNamedColumn
FROM CTE
unpivot (value FOR col IN (MERCHANDISE_AMT, FREIGHT_AMT)) u
```

Comment: With this method I don't need to output the FREIGHT_AMT column correct? FREIGHT_AMT will be output under the MERCHANDISE_AMT column on a separate row, as I have shown in my desired output above?

Comment: Yes unpivot does the opposite of pivot and breaks columns into rows.

Comment: I would want the VOUCHER_LINE_NUM to be incremented from the first row (i.e. 2)? I may have another column that I also need to unpivot into `MERCHANDISE_AMT` so I would want to have this counter. How could that be done?

Comment: you can use (VOUCHER_LINE_NUM + 1) AS VOUCHER_LINE_NUM in select clause or use row_number window function

Comment: hmmm when I use (VOUCHER_LINE_NUM + 1) in the final Select I am getting the value of 2 for each row. I should be starting at 1 and incrementing by 1 on every subsequent row, i.e. 1,2,3,4, etc...

Comment: hmmm when I use (VOUCHER_LINE_NUM + 1) in the final Select I am getting the value of 2 for each row. I should be starting at the VOUCHER_LINE_NUM from the original (non-pivoted row) row and incrementing by 1 on every subsequent row, i.e. 1,2,3,4, etc... So I could have the first row with a VOUCHER_LINE_NUM as 1, and therefore would want the 2nd (unpivoted) row with a VOUCHER_LINE_NUM of 2. Or the first row could be for example VOUCHER_LINE_NUM 3 so in this case I would want the 2nd (unpivoted) row to be a VOUCHER_LINE_NUM of 4 (incremented by 1 from whatever the first VOUCHER_LINE_NUM returned

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234899/discussion-between-nick-and-meysam-asadi).

Answer (score 0):

So you want to alias `FREIGHT_AMT` as `MERCHANDISE_AMT` and display it on a separate row?

You can use `UNION`:

```
;
with cte (
    INVOICE_ID
  , VOUCHER_LINE_NUM
  , [(No column name)]
  , MERCHANDISE_AMT
  , FREIGHT_AMT
) as (
  SELECT CONCAT(A.BUSINESS_UNIT,A.VOUCHER_ID) AS INVOICE_ID
  , A.VOUCHER_LINE_NUM
  , CASE 
      WHEN EXISTS (
          SELECT 1 
          FROM PS_DISTRIB_LINE 
          WHERE BUSINESS_UNIT = A.BUSINESS_UNIT
            AND VOUCHER_ID = A.VOUCHER_ID
            AND VOUCHER_LINE_NUM = A.VOUCHER_LINE_NUM
        )
        THEN 'ITEM'
      ELSE 'MISCELLANEOUS'
    END
  , A.MERCHANDISE_AMT
  , A.FREIGHT_AMT

  FROM FROM PS_VOUCHER_LINE A
    LEFT OUTER JOIN PS_DISTRIB_LINE B ON B.BUSINESS_UNIT = A.BUSINESS_UNIT AND B.VOUCHER_ID = A.VOUCHER_ID AND B.VOUCHER_LINE_NUM = A.VOUCHER_LINE_NUM
    LEFT OUTER JOIN PS_VOUCHER C ON C.BUSINESS_UNIT = A.BUSINESS_UNIT AND C.VOUCHER_ID = A.VOUCHER_ID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN PS_VCHR_LINE_WTHD D ON D.BUSINESS_UNIT = A.BUSINESS_UNIT AND D.VOUCHER_ID = A.VOUCHER_ID AND D.VOUCHER_LINE_NUM = A.VOUCHER_LINE_NUM AND D.WTHD_ENTITY = 'IRS'
    LEFT OUTER JOIN PS_VCHR_LINE_WTHD DD ON DD.BUSINESS_UNIT = D.BUSINESS_UNIT AND DD.VOUCHER_ID = D.VOUCHER_ID AND DD.VOUCHER_LINE_NUM = D.VOUCHER_LINE_NUM AND DD.WTHD_ENTITY = 'PA'
    LEFT OUTER JOIN PS_VENDOR E ON E.BUSINESS_UNIT = B.BUSINESS_UNIT_GL AND E.VENDOR_ID = A.VENDOR_ID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN #CloudXWalk F ON F.BUSINESS_UNIT = B.BUSINESS_UNIT_GL AND (F.DEPTID = 'All' OR F.DEPTID = B.DEPTID)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN #CloudCostCenter H ON H.BUSINESS_UNIT = B.BUSINESS_UNIT_GL AND H.DEPTID = B.DEPTID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN #CloudProjectCodes G ON G.PS_PROJECT_CODE = B.PROJECT_ID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN PS_PYMNT_VCHR_XREF I ON I.BUSINESS_UNIT = A.BUSINESS_UNIT AND I.VOUCHER_ID = A.VOUCHER_ID

  WHERE C.INVOICE_DT > '01-03-2019'
    AND C.ACCOUNTING_DT < '06-01-2021'
    --AND A.BUSINESS_UNIT = '90059'
    AND I.PYMNT_ID = ''
    AND C.CLOSE_STATUS <> 'C'
)

SELECT INVOICE_ID
, VOUCHER_LINE_NUM
, [(No column name)]
, MERCHANDISE_AMT
FROM cte

UNION
SELECT INVOICE_ID
, VOUCHER_LINE_NUM
, [(No column name)]
, FREIGHT_AMT AS MERCHANDISE_AMT
FROM cte
```

Comment: My concern with using `UNION` was that I actually have over 100 columns in my query (I removed from the above for simplicity reasons), so it may be somewhat unpractical to have to repeat every column in the UNION. Is there any use of `CROSS APPLY` that I can use that would eliminate the need to replicate every column?